# How to implement check for distinctness

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function that reads in a line of `int`s as an array. I would like to implement an additional check for distinctness in the elements. I am already checking to make sure the array values don't equal the element number.

I tried nesting another for loop to run the check within the other check but I couldn't get it to work properly.

```
int readArray(int r[SIZE]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%d", r + i);
        // check for error element number
        if (i == r[i]) {
            printf("Error: element[%d] == %d\n", i, i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I expect the function to output an error if there is a duplicate value or if the element number and value are equal.

My working solution is listed below I would like to make it a bit more concise is possible.

```
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%d", r + i);
        // check for error
        if (i == r[i]) {
            printf("Error: Element[%d] == %d\n", i, i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // check for distinctness
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if(i != j)//check indexes
            {
                if (r[i] == r[j])
                {
                    printf("Two elements repeat to %d" , i);
                    printf("\nBad input exiting program");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What did you try as the inner loop?  What upper bound did you use on it?  You should show your best effort and explain what problems you encountered.

Comment: So after you read an element, iterate over all already read elements and check if they differ from the new one.

Comment: Not a full answer, but the most efficient way would be to use a map containing the elements you've already seen. For each element, check if it's already in the map - If it is, then it's not distinct, if not, insert it into the hash. Easiest way to implement a map in C is probably hash-tables with separate chaining.

Comment: Why do you not like `i == r[i]`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not more concise, but if you want something more efficient, how about this:

```
...
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j < SIZE; j++)
...
```

That way, you skip the comparisons you already made ;)

EDIT: Oh, even better:

```
...
    for (j = i+1; j < SIZE; j++)
...
```

That way, you get rid of the:

```
if(i != j)
```